# How can I classify data with the nearest-neighbor algorithm using Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I need to classify some data with (I hope) nearest-neighbour algorithm. I've googled this problem and found a lot of libraries (including PyML, mlPy and Orange), but I'm unsure of where to start here.

How should I go about implementing k-NN using Python?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Particularly given the technique (k-Nearest Neighbors) that you mentioned in your Q, i would strongly recommend ***[scikits.learn](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/stable/)***. [*Note*: after this Answer was posted, the lead developer of this Project informed me of a [new homepage](http://scikit-learn.org) for this Project.]

A few features that i believe distinguish this library from the others (at least the other Python ML libraries that i have used, which is most of them):

- an extensive *diagnostics & testing library* (including plotting
  modules, via Matplotlib)--includes feature-selection algorithms,
  [confusion matrix](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/stable/auto_examples/plot_confusion_matrix.html), ROC, precision-recall, etc.;
- a nice selection of 'batteries-included' *data sets* (including
  handwriting digits, facial images, etc.) particularly suited for ML techniques;
- extensive *documentation* (a nice surprise given that this Project is
  only about two years old) including tutorials and step-by-step
  example code (which use the supplied data sets);

Without exception (at least that i can think of at this moment) the python ML libraries are superb. (See the [PyMVPA homepag](http://www.pymvpa.org)e for a list of the dozen or so most popular python ML libraries.)

In the past 12 months for instance, i have used *ffnet* (for MLP), *neurolab* (also for MLP), *PyBrain* (Q-Learning), *neurolab* (MLP), and *PyMVPA* (SVM) (all available from the [Python Package Index](http://pypi.python.org/))--these vary significantly from each other w/r/t maturity, scope, and supplied infrastructure, but i found them all to be of very high quality.

Still, the best of these might be ***scikits.learn***; for instance, i am not aware of any python ML library--other than scikits.learn--that includes any of the three features i mentioned above (though a few have solid example code and/or tutorials, none that i know of integrate these with a library of research-grade data sets and diagnostic algorithms).

Second, given you the technique you intend to use (*k-nearest neighbor*) scikits.learn is a particularly good choice. Scikits.learn includes kNN algorithms for both [regression](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/stable/auto_examples/plot_neighbors_regression.html) (returns a score) and [classification](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/stable/auto_examples/plot_neighbors.html) (returns a class label), as well as detailed sample code for each.

Using the scikits.learn k-nearest neighbor module (literally) couldn't be any easier:

```
>>> # import NumPy and the relevant scikits.learn module
>>> import numpy as NP
>>> from sklearn import neighbors as kNN

>>> # load one of the sklearn-suppplied data sets
>>> from sklearn import datasets
>>> iris = datasets.load_iris()
>>> # the call to load_iris() loaded both the data and the class labels, so
>>> # bind each to its own variable
>>> data = iris.data
>>> class_labels = iris.target

>>> # construct a classifier-builder by instantiating the kNN module's primary class
>>> kNN1 = kNN.NeighborsClassifier()

>>> # now construct ('train') the classifier by passing the data and class labels
>>> # to the classifier-builder
>>> kNN1.fit(data, class_labels)
      NeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, leaf_size=20, algorithm='auto')
```

What's more, unlike nearly all other ML techniques, the crux of k-nearest neighbors is not coding a working classifier builder, rather the difficult step in building a production-grade k-nearest neighbor classifier/regressor is the persistence layer--i.e., *storage and fast retrieval of the data points from which the nearest neighbors are selected*. For the kNN data storage layer, scikits.learn includes an algorithm for a ***ball tree*** (which i know almost nothing about other than is apparently superior to the *kd-tree* (the traditional data structure for k-NN) because its performance doesn't degrade in higher dimensional features space.

Additionally, k-nearest neighbors requires an appropriate similarity metric (Euclidean distance is the usual choice, though not always the best one). Scikits.learn includes a stand-along module comprised of various distance metrics as well as testing algorithms for selection of the appropriate one.

Finally, there are a few libraries that i have not mentioned either because they are out of scope (PyML, Bayesian); they are not primarily 'libraries' for developers but rather applications for end users (e.g., Orange), or they have unusual or difficult-to-install dependencies (e.g., mlpy, which requires the gsl, which in turn must be built from source) at least for my OS, which is Mac OS X.

(*Note*: i am not a developer/committer for scikits.learn.)

Comment: Thank you for such detailed answer. I'll probably start with scikits.learn now.

Comment: Thanks Doug for the answer. As a developer for the scikit-learn, I am much honored. I couple of remarks that people might find useful in the long run. First, starting from version 0.10, the imports have changed from scikits.learn to sklearn. Second, the website for scikit-learn is moving to http://scikit-learn.org

Comment: @GaelVaroquaux That's very useful, Gael--i'll put edit my answer to include it. (And thanks for creating a world-class ML library--as you can tell by my answer above, i am obviously a fan.)